# Parsing a List of Values Python

Tags: python, list, boto

I have a function that returns a list of values:

```
vpn = conn.get_all_vpn_connections()
```

Here is what is returned:

```
[VpnConnection:someidxx1, VpnConnection:someidxx2, VpnConnection:someidxx3, VpnConnection:someidxx4]
```

I want to store whats returned in a variable and loop through it. What would a function look like that would do that?

Comment: Erm, a for loop?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Is it returning a list, or a string that *looks* like a list literal?

Answer (score 0):

You've already stored what's returned in the variable 'vpn'. Assuming that it's returning a list, to loop through it you'd just use a simple for loop...

```
vpn = conn.get_all_vpn_connections()
for vpn_connection in vpn:
    print vpn_connection
```

If it's not a list, you'll have to check it's variable class with

```
print type(vpn)
```

And let us know what it is.